# Regex on Perl to capture this type of value (a)(2)

Tags: regex, perl

I'm working on perl to capture this this part of the HTML file so for example:

I'm using this regex `([0-9]{4}).([0-9]{4})` to capture this `1910.1024`. But some portion of the HTML file have this kind of value `1910.1024(a)(2)`. I don't know the proper way to captured this two parentheses with a value inside it. I will be using this regex to my Perl script to substitute this a link.

My script now is capturing this value `1910.1024`, I want to know on how to captured this `1910.1024(a)(2)` one.

```
if($content =~ m/([0-9]{4}).([0-9]{4})/gm){
   $content =~ s/([0-9]{4}).([0-9]{4})/<!!uf dp_ecfr29 29cfr$1x$2 #29cfr$1x$2>$1.$2<\/a>/gm;
}
elsif($content2 =~ m/([0-9]{4})\.([0-9]{4})(?:\((\w+)\))?(?:\((\w+)\))/gm){
   $content2 =~ s~([0-9]{4})\.([0-9]{4})(?:\((\w+)\))?(?:\((\w+)\))?~<!!uf dp_ecfr29 29cfr$1x$2 #29cfr$1x$2z-$3-$4>$1.$2($3)($4)</a>~g; 
}
elsif($content3 =~ m/([0-9]{4})\.([0-9]{4})(?:\((\w+)\))/gm){
   $content3 =~ s~([0-9]{4})\.([0-9]{4})(?:\((\w+)\))?~<!!uf dp_ecfr29 29cfr$1x$2 #29cfr$1x$2z-$3>$1.$2($3)</a>~g; 
} 
else {
   printf "Error";
}
```

Comment: You probably need `$content =~ s~([0-9]{4})\.([0-9]{4})(?:\(\w+\))*~<!!uf dp_ecfr29 29cfr$1x$2 #29cfr$1x$2>$1.$2</a>~g;`

Comment: Or optionally match 2 times a pair of parenthesis inside group 2 if you want to keep it `([0-9]{4})\.([0-9]{4}(?:\([a-z]+\)\(\d+\))?)` https://regex101.com/r/q0jZjq/1

Comment: Hello how can I captured one at a time ? like 1910 = $1 1924 = $2 and (a) = $3 and (3) = to $4 ? because what i'm gonna do is to changed all 1910.1924 into this format <!!uf dp_ecfr29 29cfr1910x1024 #29cfr1910x1024>1910.1024</a> and this 1910.1030(f)(1)(ii) into this <!!uf dp_ecfr29 29cfr1910x1030 #29cfr1910x1030zf-1-ii-d> format. so I have to captured each to change the format. Thanks for the help

Comment: `$content =~ s~([0-9]{4})\.([0-9]{4})(?:\((\w+)\))?(?:\((\w+)\))?~<!!uf dp_ecfr29 29cfr$1x$2 #29cfr$1x$2>$1.$2</a>~g;`

Comment: Hello Wiktor, Thank you everything seems to be working just fine but my concern is when i tried this on Perl script it is not working according to what I expected. I'm new to programming i dont know if my syntax is correct, i'll put the script above for your reference . if you could help me on this that would be great thank you .

Comment: John, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a couple of optional capturing groups in the regex pattern and then a couple of conditions in the replacement part.

As the regex is quite long, you may use the `/x` flag to break it on separate lines.

See the [Perl demo](https://ideone.com/99hGSd):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use feature "say";
use strict;
use warnings;

my $content = "I am trying to capture this 1910.1024,  this 1910.1024(a) and  this 1910.1024(a)(3).";
if($content =~ m/([0-9]{4})\.([0-9]{4})/) {
   $content =~ s{
        ([0-9]{4})      # $1 = First 4 digits
        \.              # Dot
        ([0-9]{4})      # $2 = Second 4 digits
        (?:\((\w+)\))?  # (, $3 (first optional "word"), )
        (?:\((\w+)\))?  # (, $4 (second optional "word"), )
    }{
        "<!!uf dp_ecfr29 29cfr$1x$2 #29cfr$1x$2" .
        (defined($3) ? "z-$3" : "") . (defined($4) ? "-$4" : "") .
        ">$1.$2" . 
        (defined($3) ? "($3)" : "") . (defined($4) ? "($4)" : "") . 
        "</a>"
    }gxe;
    say "$content\n";
} else {
   say "Error";
}
```

Output:

```perl
I am trying to capture this <!!uf dp_ecfr29 29cfr1910x1024 #29cfr1910x1024>1910.1024</a>,  this <!!uf dp_ecfr29 29cfr1910x1024 #29cfr1910x1024z-a>1910.1024(a)</a> and  this <!!uf dp_ecfr29 29cfr1910x1024 #29cfr1910x1024z-a-3>1910.1024(a)(3)</a>.
```

See the `gxe`, `x` helps break the pattern into multiple lines and add comments, `g` matches all occurrences in the string and `e` helps intepret the RHS as a Perl expression where we can introduce custom replacing logic.

Constructions like `(defined($3) ? "z-$3" : "")` check if Group 3 matched, and then use one replacement text or another.

Comment: Thank you very much Wiktor, I learned so much from your explanation. I'll study it more and improve my perl programming  skills. Thank you so much.

Comment: also Wiktor I noticed that I have this data that I need to capture 1910.1030(f)(1)(ii)(D) , how can I edit the script to get this data also ?

Comment: @johndenverabella It is the same logic, add two more `(?:\((\w+)\))?` at the regex end, and then add two `(defined($x) ? "($x)" : "")` (replacing `x` with the Group ID) where expected.

Comment: Hi Wiktor , I'm having trouble getting this data 1910.141(d)(2) , can you help on this ? would greatly appreciated . thank you

Comment: @johndenverabella Use `\d{3,4}` as the ending pattern part, see [this Perl demo](https://ideone.com/weEpGa).

Comment: Wiktor if I need to capture this type of data 45 C.F.R. § 102.3 the output needs to be like this <!!uf dp_ecfr45 45cfr103x3 #45cfr102x3>102.3</a> I'm having a hard  time capturing this type of data because it need to be sorted out by the 45 CFR unlike 29 CFR. hope you could help me on this , I am learning so much on this.